# Daedalus wallet recovery phrase to Cardano Wallet Backend mnemonic sentence + mnemonic second factor

Tags: wallet, daedalus, cardano-node, api, recovery

Daedalus wallet recovery phrase is 24 words. Cardano Wallet Backend mnemonic sentence is 15 words and mnemonic second factor is 9 words, adding up to 24 words.

I tried restoring a wallet through [Cardano Wallet Backend API](https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/api/edge/#operation/postWallet) by taking the first 15 words of the Daedalus wallet recovery phrase as an input for `mnemonic_sentence` and rest of the 9 words as an input for `mnemonic_second_factor`. Unfortunately, this does not work as the last word of the `mnemonic_sentence` produces an incorrect checksum.

Is there a way I can restore a wallet through the API knowing a Daedalus wallet recovery phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mnemonic_sentence` can be between 15 and 24 words. The `mnemonic_second_factor` is optional. So you can simply pass all your 24 words in as `mnemonic_sentence` and don't set the `mnemonic_second_factor` and you should be able to restore your wallet.

[image]

Source: https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/api/edge/#operation/postWallet

Comment: I've tried this as well but using 15 words & I keep getting `wallet_already_exists` error. Does this mean I can't restore a wallet that was created by the `cardano-wallet` server in the past?